# InfoPath code behind using CSOM does not execute correctly

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, csom

I have built an InfoPath 2013 Form which uses code behind and the SharePoint 2013 CSOM Managed API to query and manipulate a list.  The Form works perfectly when run from the Desktop but when displayed as a web page using Form Services the CSOM code does not even appear to connect to the site.  All Queries return null and all properties of the calendar object are uninitialized.

```
ClientContext client = new ClientContext(siteURL);
List calender = client.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("IT Calendar");

CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
ListItemCollection entries = calender.GetItems(query);

client.Load(entries, c => c.Where(i => i.ContentType.Id.StringValue == typeId));
client.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: The problem of course as I discovered is that in Desktop mode the ClientContext assumes the Credentials of the executing user.  In Browser mode this does not happen (it will make the CSOM calls anonymously). You must set the Credentials property of the ClientContext explicitly.

Comment: If that's your answer, feel free to post it as an answer. It will certainly help future users with a similar issue.